# Why is JobConsumer not being hit/run?

Tags: rabbitmq, .net-6.0, masstransit

I am trying out the new `MassTransit` `IJobConsumer` implementation, and although I've tried to follow the documentation, the `JobConsumer` I have written is never being run/hit.

I have:

- created the `JobConsumer` which has a run method that runs the code I need it to

  ```
    public class CalculationStartRunJobConsumer : IJobConsumer<ICalculationStartRun> 
    {
        private readonly ICalculationRunQueue runQueue;

        public CalculationStartRunJobConsumer(ICalculationRunQueue runQueue)
        {
            this.runQueue = runQueue;
        }

        public Task Run(JobContext<ICalculationStartRun> context)
        {
            return Task.Run(
                () =>
                {
                    var longRunningJob = new LongRunningJob<ICalculationStartRun>
                    {
                        Job = context.Job,
                        CancellationToken = context.CancellationToken,
                        JobId = context.JobId,
                    };

                    runQueue.StartSpecial(longRunningJob);
                },
                context.CancellationToken);
        } 
    }
  ```
- I have registered that consumer trying both `ConnectReceiveEndpoint` and `AddConsumer`
- Configured the `ServiceInstance` as shown in the documentation

  ```
    services.AddMassTransit(busRegistrationConfigurator =>
        {
            // TODO: Get rid of this ugly if statement.
            if (consumerTypes != null)
            {
                foreach (var consumerType in consumerTypes)
                {
                    busRegistrationConfigurator.AddConsumer(consumerType);
                }
            }

            if(requestClientType != null)
            {
                busRegistrationConfigurator.AddRequestClient(requestClientType);
            }

            busRegistrationConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
                cfg.UseNewtonsoftJsonDeserializer();
                cfg.ConfigureNewtonsoftJsonSerializer(settings =>
                {
                    // The serializer by default omits fields that are set to their default value, but this causes unintended effects
                    settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
                    settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
                    return settings;
                });

                cfg.Host(
                    messagingHostInfo.HostAddress,
                    hostConfigurator =>
                    {
                        hostConfigurator.Username(messagingHostInfo.UserName);
                        hostConfigurator.Password(messagingHostInfo.Password);
                    });

                cfg.ServiceInstance(instance =>
                {
                    instance.ConfigureJobServiceEndpoints(serviceCfg =>
                    {
                        serviceCfg.FinalizeCompleted = true;
                    });

                    instance.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });
        });
  ```
- Seen that the queue for the job does appear in the queue for `RabbitMQ`
- When I call `.Send` to send a message to that queue, it does not activate the `Run` method on the `JobConsumer`.

  ```
    public async Task Send<T>(string queueName, T message) where T : class
    {
        var endpointUri = GetEndpointUri(messagingHostInfo.HostAddress, queueName);
        var sendEndpoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(endpointUri);

        await sendEndpoint.Send(message);
    }
  ```

Can anyone help?

**Software**

- `MassTransit` 8.0.2
- `MassTransit.RabbitMq` 8.0.2
- `MassTransit.NewtonsoftJson` 8.0.2
- `.NET6`
- Using in-memory for `JobConsumer`

Comment: I'd suggest [starting with a sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-JobConsumers) and figure out what you did wrong. Beyond that, reviewing the logs with the log level set to DEBUG is your best way to figure out why something isn't working.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have now updated the question with the code snippets. See anything wrong there, or that needs explanation? I had looked already at the sample and could not see why this solution would not work. Trying looking at the DEBUG logs also and found nothing of use unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup of any type of repository for long running jobs is missing. We needed to either:

- explicitly specify that it was using InMemory (missing from the docs)
- Setup saga repositories using e.g. EF Core.

As recommended by MassTransit, we went with the option of setting up saga repositories by implementing databases and interacting with them using EF Core.